# Node.js Passport not calling next function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm building an application using Node that uses Passport.js to handle user login using a local database.

So I have the following code that gets called when a user goes to /profile. After successfully logging in the user gets redirected to /profile. Which does happen according to morgan.

```
app.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('local-login', { session : false, failureRedirect : '/login' }), function(req, res) {
    console.log("testnow");
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
```

My local-login code is the following.

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

        // all is well, return successful user
        console.log("testdone");
        return done(null, user);
    });
}));
```

When testing the code I login and get redirected to profile for a split second. The console prints "testdone" which is in my local-login code BUT doesn't print "testnow" as it is expected to. Meaning the second function in my /profile get method never seems to get called even tho local-login is calling the next function.

So from the end users standpoint you login (behind the scenes you get redirected to /profile for a split section) and /profile redirects you back to /login.

Any ideas on how to fix this so the second function in my /profile get method actually gets called?

Thanks so much in advance. I would also be more then happy to provide any additional information to help figure this out.

Comment: Try to add an attribute to the options object at the pasport.authenticate this: `successRedirect : '/profile'` and create a route /profile in case of success, i don't know if passport calls next function after you're authenticate omitting successRedirect

Comment: @FernandoZamperin Adding a success redirect /profile will cause an infinite loop tho correct?

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood!!! Try to successRedirect to another route just for test purposes to see if the problem is that passport is not calling next

Comment: @FernandoZamperin Yeah that didn't work. Still redirecting to /login. Changed it to "app.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('local-login', { session : false, successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect : '/login' }), function(req, res) {" and still redirecting to /login instead of /

Comment: If you disable sessions, how does Passport know if a user has logged in or not?

Comment: @robertklep Ok true. Although that didn't fix the problem. Still being redirected back to /login.

Comment: Have you implemented `passport.serializeUser()/deserializeUser()`? What's the configuration of `express-session`?

Comment: @robertklep Yep https://gist.github.com/fishcharlie/73e42d7cefd2ff148045c43415f5541f is the code for those two methods

Comment: @robertklep if session is set to false is it necessary to implement `passport.serializeUser()/passport.deserializeUser()` ?

Comment: @robertklep Not sure quite what you mean by configuration of express-session

Comment: @FernandoZamperin no, but if session is set to false Passport will never know that the user was successfully logged in :)

Comment: @CharlieFish [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) is required to enable session support in Passport.

Comment: @robertklep That's right. `app.use(session({ secret: 'eZjxi*MvnL)jDWci%p)293ub*7g>v9R3?7JQ{B=Jq+b2ZN8L4', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions`

Comment: @robertklep It defiantly looks like it's always calling the failureRedirect. When removing failureRedirect it just gives me a "Bad Request".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`passport.authenticate()` is meant to handle the actual authentication; in other words, to take the login credentials and pass them to the strategy. It's not meant to pass along requests if they are already authenticated, which is what you're trying to use it for.

Instead, you want to use something like [`connect-ensure-login`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login) to guard routes for which a user has to be logged in.

See also [this Passport example project](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js#L88).

Comment: Ok cool. So pretty much have to kinda change my direction. Thanks so much.