# Passport OAuth Bearer OR isAuthenticated

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I have been searching to see if this is possible for a while and haven't found anything.

Basically I'm using [Passport](http://passportjs.org) to handle user authentication. Of course using Node.js and Express to handle the server side of things. I'm also using [oauth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) to allow OAuth and handle API calls.

For API calls, I use the middleware `controllerClient.isBearerAuthenticated` which runs `passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false })`. Then that goes off and runs the function inside of `passport.use("bearer", new BearerStrategy)`. Basically checking to see if the token is valid and calling the callback function.

For non API requests and just normal web pages it runs the following middleware to check for authentication.

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

So here's my problem. I want to allow my API calls to be accessed if there is a bearer token **OR** `req.isAuthenticated()` = true. Currently I have to choose if I want to use `isLoggedIn` middleware or `controllerClient.isBearerAuthenticated` middleware. I'm trying to find a way to combine them in like an or statement or something.

I was thinking about having multiple middleware functions so it calls `isLoggedIn` then calls `controllerClient.isBearerAuthenticated`. But it seems like the problem with that would be the callback functions would get called so they would both get called. I was also researching to figure out if there is a way to like skip over the next middleware function and go to the next one but I couldn't find anything regarding that either.

I think the best bet would be to figure out a way to skip over the `controllerClient.isBearerAuthenticated` **IF** `req.isAuthenticated()` = true. Now there might be a better way to do this and if so I would love to hear it.

But any suggestions on how to use middleware to check to see if the user is autheroized via `req.isAuthenticated()` **OR** `controllerClient.isBearerAuthenticated`? Or what the best way to achieve this is?

> **One more note.** I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402929/node-js-passport-not-calling-next-function) question before and figured out that `passport.authenticate` is meant to handle the actual
>   authentication not users that have already been authenticated.
>   Otherwise I would just use `passport.authenticate` with an array of
>   Passport strategies. And using [connect-ensure-login](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login) would have the same issue as I have right now about using connect-ensure-login OR `controllerClient.isBearerAuthenticated`.

**Thanks** so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution that seems to be working. For future reference and for people who might be having a similar issue I will post my solution below.

Basically making one middleware function with the following code seemed to work.

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    //Checking to see if user is authenticated on the web
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    //If not checking to see if user is authenticated via Bearer and OAuth
    else {
        return controllerClient.isBearerAuthenticated.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

So we are just checking to see if `req.isAuthenticated` is equal to true. If it is we are just returning the callback function and the API function will be called. If not then we check the `controllerClient.isBearerAuthenticated` which will call the next function automatically it looks like if successful. If not it will send `Unauthorized` with a status code of 401.

Would be nice to figure out how exactly to change the `Unauthorized` message but will hopefully look into that down the road.